# JSCS validateJSDoc Error Unsupported Rule on Closure or Comment at the Top of the File

Tags: angularjs, gulp, jscs, gulp-jscs

I've setup JShint and JSCS using Gulp for an AngularJS app using the JShint and JSCS docs for options, and JSHint work as it should, but when used with JSCS I get a bunch of errors all one per file all associated to the IIFE or comment at the top of the files.

```
gulp.task('vet', function () {

    var files = [
        './resources/assets/js/**/*.js',
        '!./resources/assets/js/services/services.httpi.js',
        './*.js'
    ];

    return gulp.src(files)
               .pipe(jscs())
               .pipe(jscs.reporter())
               .pipe(jshint())
               .pipe(jshint.reporter('jshint-stylish', {verbose: true}));
});
```

But when I run the vet task I get this error for all my files:

```
[15:15:41] Starting 'vet'...
Unsupported rule: validateJSDoc at D:\projects\app\resources\assets\js\app.config.js :
     1 |(function () {
--------^
     2 |
     3 |    'use strict';
```

I've tried moving 'use strict' out of the closure (sloppy, but needed to see if it worked)

Alternatively I also tried adding a comment before the closure, but get the same error, but instead it points to the comment:

```
2 code style errors found.
Unsupported rule: validateJSDoc at D:\projects\app\resources\assets\js\app.module.js :
     1 |/**
--------^
     2 | * Application Module
     3 | * @namespace Application
```

Are JSCS expect files to start with something specific?  Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [available JSCS rules](http://jscs.info/rules). There's not `validateJSDoc`, only [`jsDoc`](http://jscs.info/rule/jsDoc). The reason being that `validateJSDoc` was [deprectated and dropped in JSCS 2.0](https://github.com/jscs-dev/node-jscs/issues/993).

Either remove that rule from your `.jscsrc` (or whatever config file you use) or fix it to make it compatible with the newer `jsDoc`.

Comment: Thanks I missed that validateJSDoc was not jsDoc.  That said now I have this error: `Error running rule jsDoc: This is an issue with JSCS and not your codebase.
Please file an issue (with the stack trace below) at: https://github.com/jscs-dev/node-jscs/issues/new
TypeError: node.getFirstToken is not a function`.  Have you seen this before?

Comment: I posted the issue on [Github](https://github.com/jscs-dev/node-jscs/issues/2241) as they suggested.